# install curl and readr on R

Tags: r, curl

Greeting dear community. I try to install readr but it gives me an error because of there is no curl. I then try to install curl and it asks for another dependency. I verify that in the command prompt but it looks like its already installed. Any idea ?  See blow:
Many Thanks

Try to install readr:

```
> install.packages("readr")
Installing package into ‘/home/oracle/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘curl’

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/curl_0.9.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 242408 bytes (236 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 236 Kb

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/readr_0.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 322890 bytes (315 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 315 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
File curl.h not found. Make sure the curl development library is installed, e.g. libcurl4-openssl-dev (deb) or libcurl-devel (rpm).
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/oracle/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1/curl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘curl’ is not available for package ‘readr’
* removing ‘/home/oracle/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1/readr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘readr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpuTNCiG/downloaded_packages’
```

Try to install curl

```
> install.packages("curl")
Installing package into ‘/home/oracle/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/curl_0.9.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 242408 bytes (236 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 236 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
File curl.h not found. Make sure the curl development library is installed, e.g. libcurl4-openssl-dev (deb) or libcurl-devel (rpm).
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/oracle/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1/curl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpuTNCiG/downloaded_packages’
```

Install curl in terminal:

```
[oracle@localhost data]$ sudo yum -y install curl
Loaded plugins: langpacks
Package curl-7.29.0-19.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[oracle@localhost data]$ sudo yum -y install libcurl
Loaded plugins: langpacks
Package libcurl-7.29.0-19.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

It looks like libcurl is there ?

```
[oracle@localhost data]$ locate libcurl 
/home/oracle/anaconda/lib/libcurl.a
/home/oracle/anaconda/lib/libcurl.la
/home/oracle/anaconda/lib/libcurl.so
/home/oracle/anaconda/lib/libcurl.so.4
/home/oracle/anaconda/lib/libcurl.so.4.3.0
/home/oracle/anaconda/lib/pkgconfig/libcurl.pc
/home/oracle/anaconda/pkgs/curl-7.38.0-0/lib/libcurl.a
/home/oracle/anaconda/pkgs/curl-7.38.0-0/lib/libcurl.la
/home/oracle/anaconda/pkgs/curl-7.38.0-0/lib/libcurl.so
/home/oracle/anaconda/pkgs/curl-7.38.0-0/lib/libcurl.so.4
/home/oracle/anaconda/pkgs/curl-7.38.0-0/lib/libcurl.so.4.3.0
/home/oracle/anaconda/pkgs/curl-7.38.0-0/lib/pkgconfig/libcurl.pc
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4.3.0
```

So does the curl-config is there..

```
[oracle@localhost data]$ locate curl-config
/home/oracle/anaconda/bin/curl-config
/home/oracle/anaconda/pkgs/curl-7.38.0-0/bin/curl-config
[oracle@localhost data]$
```

Answer (score 76):

I solved the problem on **Ubuntu 14.04** by using this command

`sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`

Future users can search for the latest libcurl using:
`apt-cache search libcurl`

Comment: I also had a similar issue (missing curl ) while installing packages in r on **Ubuntu 16.04**, and `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev ` saved the trouble.

Comment: I just used this while installing packages in *Ubuntu 18.04* and it also worked for me. Big thanks, much love.

Answer (score 18):

The actual problem is:

> File curl.h not found.

R suggests a solution:

> Make sure the curl development library is installed, e.g. libcurl4-openssl-dev (deb) or libcurl-devel (rpm)

So, try:

```
sudo yum -y install libcurl-devel
```

Comment: Wow. I should've tried reading the error message a little better. I was so focused on `missing package libcurl` that I completely ignored that. Thanks!