# Trouble installing the`curl` package in R 4.3. Message about `package or namespace load failed for ‘curl’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):`

Tags: r, linux, curl, environment-variables

I trying to install the `curl` package in R, but am running into a bunch of errors. I am running on Ubuntu Linux 20.04. I think the problem might be due to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, which is rather bulky on my system--due to Intel Oneapi and such.

I tried to install the `curl` package from both the standard repo as well as from the source tar.gz file, but I get the same error message as below:

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘curl’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/krishnab/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/00LOCK-curl/00new/curl/libs/curl.so':
  /home/krishnab/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/00LOCK-curl/00new/curl/libs/curl.so: undefined symbol: curl_easy_option_next
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/krishnab/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/curl’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpaDqBoZ/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("curl") :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have the appropriate `libcurl` packages installed, so I don't think that is the problem.
I think perhaps starting my R session with an empty LD_LIBRARY_PATH might work, but I am not sure. I believe the current LD_LIBRARY_PATH is pointing to the wrong locations for `curl` and that is preventing R from finding the `curl` executable.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You wrote "I have the appropriate libcurl packages installed." But the failure is due to this error: `undefined symbol: curl_easy_option_next`. Which suggests to me you either don't have the appropriate libcurl package.

Comment: @KurtisRader That is true. I was trying to find a reference online for that function, `curl_easy_option_next` but I have not really found anything. I did install `curl` with `sudo apt-get install curl` as well as the `libcurl4-openssl-dev` package as well. I could compile `curl` from scratch and install curl 8.1.2, but I am not sure if that will mess up something else? I followed this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686470/install-curl-and-readr-on-r

Comment: See https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_option_next.html where it says "This function was added in libcurl 7.73.0". I would assume you have installed an older version of libcurl. Furthermore, the current stable version is 8.1.2 so whatever you are using is pretty old.